# Orange box around links

Tags: html, hyperlink

Recently orange boxes started appearing around links on my page and I don't know why.

I didn't do anything to make that happen and I can't find anything in the CSS indicating that that should be happening.

On my homepage: http://ultimatemmo.webege.com/index.html notice how when you click on the links in the site navigation bar or the links on top, there's an orange box around them when you click on them.

This happens on some pages but not others, and some links but not others.

Can anyone think of a reason for this? Has anyone else had this problem?

I couldn't find anything on this site or on google about it.

**Edit:** I also just checked the links using Chrome Developer Tools and I couldn't find any style rules indication why this is happening

Comment: Err, well, when you get that page it says it supports chrome, firefox, and safari. Did you try one of those? Because if you did, then I have to change things.

Comment: @MarkH Which four? Chrome, Firefox and Safari seem to be supported. That leaves IE, Opera, and?

Comment: Edit: My mistake, it does work in firefox.

Comment: @MarkKramer How to you identify the browser? User agent string?

Comment: Hmm, that's wierd, I just tried Firefox 5 and it worked for me. Oh well, I'll change my script just so it specifically doesn't support IE and Opera

Comment: No, I use a special plugin because of the problems associated with agent string

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Comment: @MarkKramer That plug-in does use the user agent string to identify the browser. Don't use that plug-in. If you want to identify modern browsers, use feature detection.

Comment: Oh wow, I just found out he published a new script. I'll use that one and see if it works any better. http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2006/07/browser_detect.html

Comment: @MarkKramer Sir, listen to me. Browser detection scripts are not a good idea. Google "browser feature detection"...

Comment: Yes, yes, I know, if my site was a 'real' site, I wouldn't use them, but it's not. It's just a personal project I'm working on that has like three people who visit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `outline: none;` to your `a` rule:

```
a {
    ...
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: This worked, although I'm curious why I need this now when I didn't before.

Comment: @MarkKramer It's because of the `tabindex` attribute. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/auvGP/

Comment: Hmm, that would make sense. Thanks =)